# How to extract Data from Cdata in XML (WP All Import)

Tags: xml, wordpress, cdata

Hi I'm using WP All Import to process an XML Feed of events. The feed does not include the venue as a separate path but in CDATA which looks like this:

```
<name>
<![CDATA[ 31 May 2022 - 19:00 @ Strand Arts Centre - (opening time 18:00) Test Show please ignore this ]]>
</name>
```

The venue always appears after the @ and before –
So I assume I need to run some sort of pre replace to extract everything between the two symbols, but not sure how to do this. Any help appreaciated.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve it myself by adding this function:

```
function get_string_between ($str) {
    $from = '@';
    $to = '-';
    $string = substr($str, strpos($str, $from) + strlen($from));

    if (strstr ($string,$to,TRUE) != FALSE) {

        $string = strstr ($string,$to,TRUE);

    }

    return $string;

}
```

and then added this to the wp all import field for venue:

```
[get_string_between({name})]
```